# Why can't I jailbreak iPod Touch 4g 4.3.3 (8j2)?

Tags: ipod-touch, jailbreak

Every time I go to jailbreakme.com on my device, the site says "Not supported on your device."

Like I said, I have an iPod Touch 4g, ios 4.3.3. And the site clearly says my version and device is supported. Help please, thank you.

Comment: I found the answer. I was using a different browser than Safari. :)

Comment: Post it as a real answer using the "Answer your Question" button below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: I was not using Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to Settings>General>International and choose region format "Hawaii United States". Then open www.jailbreakme.com again from Safari.